# como seleccionar correctamente el valor del input en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Estoy tratando de guardar en una variable el valor introducido en un input y mostrar por consola al pulsar enter pero no logro que funcione ya que el console log es vacio siempre.

```js
let $opcion = $(".opcion");
let $contenido = $(".valor").val();
      $(".valor").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          // Acciones que relizamos
          console.log($contenido);
          $opcion.submit();
        }
      });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="opcion">
<input type="text" class="valor" value="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente, la asignación de la variable puede estar dentro de la acción como aquí:

```js
 let $opcion = $(".opcion");
      $(".valor").keypress(function (e) {
      let $contenido = $(".valor").val();

        if (e.which == 13) {
          // Acciones que relizamos
          console.log($contenido);
          $opcion.submit();
        }
      });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="opcion">
<input type="text" class="valor" value="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ese era el error :)

Comment: Ha sido un gusto poder ayudarte.